# std::unordered_set::erase complexity

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, unordered

I don't understand, why has *erase* method of *std::unordered_set* O(N) complexity in worst case (where N is number of elements)? Standard (n4296) says what all three versions of *erase* method have O(a.size()) complexity in worst case (*a* is container), and invalidated only iterators which point to erased elements, but not all iterators (i.e. rehashing doesn't take place). This is true even for a version which takes one iterator argument and have constant complexity in average case. I think it is because that *erase* version returns an iterator to the next element, and this requires finding the first non-empty bucket after erased element, and it gives O(a.bucket_count()) complexity, but not O(a.size())!. Number of elements is not in direct ratio to the number of buckets. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> aSet;
    aSet.insert ({125, 126});
    aSet.rehash (1000);
    cout << aSet.size() << endl;
    cout << aSet.bucket_count() << endl;
}
```

Output is

```
Size: 2
Bucket count: 1031
```

The size of a container is only 2 and bucket_count is 1031. When *erase* method will be called, it will seek next non-empty bucket, which can be placed about the end, i.e. complexity is O(a.bucket_count()), but not O(a.size()). What is reason for which Standard gives O(a.size()) complexity?

Comment: In think the existing answers misunderstand the question. A good implementation does not have to look in every bucket to find the element to erase, with the exception of the worst case when all of the buckets are full. Therefore, the complexity is smaller than `O(a.bucket_count())` unless `a.bucket_count()` is the same or larger than `a.size()`.

Comment: The `O(bucket_count())` part is incorrect. See [LWG 579](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#579).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is true even for a version which takes one iterator argument and
>   have constant complexity in average case.

The unordered associative containers have forward iterators - they are allowed to be implemented via singly linked lists.

Erasing a node involves relinking the node before it to the node after it. Finding the node before the one the iterator points to can be worst-case `O(N)` in a singly-linked-list-based implementation, because you'll basically have to traverse the bucket (which can contain every element in the container in the fully colliding case).

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious reason is that a degenerate hashing function may yield the same value for all elements. As a result they'd all be sorted into the same bucket. Although it is unlikely, the same *could* happen even with a reasonably good hashing function, especially after mapping the values to buckets afain. Since there is no reasonable specification for the quality of the hashing function the standard can't mandate a better time complexity.

Comment: Well, I don't see why it can't be constant complexity for `erase(iterator)` if we have a doubly-linked-list based implementation.

Answer (score 3):

> What is reason for which Standard gives O(a.size()) complexity?

`std::unordered_set` is a hashed container. If the provided hash function maps to the same value for each element inserted into the container, then they will be chained together (presumably in a linked list). So in the worst case, a single 'list' could contain all items in the container and like any 'find' operation, `erase` is worse case linear in the number of elements.